# Celery crontab to schedule 1 of the month and quarterly in year

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a celery task which executes quarterly on 1 of the month how can my month_of_year can be written

```
{
    'task': 'mytask',
    'schedule': crontab(day_of_month='1', month_of_year='')
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `month_of_year='*/3'` to run every quarter month

```
{
    'task': 'mytask',
    'schedule': crontab(0, 0, day_of_month='1', month_of_year='*/3')
},
```